correct phrase [long from now] vs [a long time from now]
I have made up the sentences below.
(1) I just came back from my last trip. My next one will be long from now.
(2) I just came back from my last trip. My next one will be a long time from now.
Which one is correct? Thanks.

(1) is definitely wrong, and (2) isn't very idiomatic. It would be much more natural to say "It'll be a long time before I have another" or "...until my next one".

"It is long from now" is not the usual idiomatic way of expressing that something is a long time away.
Looking at the Corpus of Contemporary American English, "long from now" is almost always used in negative expressions like "it is not long from now" or questions like "how long from now...?" (also a few examples of "too long from now"). So it's certainly not standard in this context. "My next one will not be long from now" sounds much more idiomatic than "My next one will be long from now." This is one of several cases in English where a word is more common or usual in a negative context than a positive one.
This question and answer explains the idiom "be a long time". It's an idiom meaning "take a long time" or "will not occur soon".
"I just came back from my last trip. My next one will be a long time from now." is valid English, but it's probably not the most usual way of expressing it. You could say it if you have a trip planned at a specific date in the distant future. But if you just mean "I don't know when I will travel, but I don't think it will be soon", then it's not the most normal way of expressing that ("I'm not going on another trip for a long time.", "It was my last trip for a long time." etc would be more common in my opinion.)
